# How to achieve Dynamic SQL Query with Multiple parmeters to handle null values also

Tags: sql-server

My code logic is given below, when one of my input parameter passed as null, the parameterlist should be managed according, how could i proceed for this.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @paramlist NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @SQL='select [Company ID],
[QSS Company ID],
[Company Name],
[Inactive]  from Company WHERE 1=1'

IF @CompanyID IS NOT NULL
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ([Company ID] = @CompanyID)'
Select @paramlist=@paramlist+'@CompanyID BIGINT'
IF @QSSCompanyID IS NOT NULL
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ([QSS Company ID] = @QSSCompanyID)'
IF @CompanyName IS NOT NULL
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' AND ([QSS Company ID] = @CompanyName)'


EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@CompanyID BIGINT, @QSSCompanyID BIGINT, 
@CompanyName  nvarchar',  @CompanyID,@QSSCompanyID,@CompanyName
```

Comment: You should always use `BEGIN/END` around the output of a conditional. That way it doesn't matter if you execute 1 command or 50, the result will never be an unexpected one. In the code you have, `@paramlist` will *always* include `@CompanyID BIGINT` even when `@CompanyID` is null.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Begin/End is their in stored proc, i have extracted the logic alone. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no harm in having unused parameters passed into sp_executesql.

You approach above is correct.  Declare and pass in all possible parameters for sp_executesql.  You will still get all the benefits of dynamic sql even with unused parameters.

Comment: You could do it dynamically but it would be really, really, really ugly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Can you help me, how can we do the better approach

Comment: @strayCatDBA its my bad ([QSS Company ID] = @CompanyName) im assigning the value company name to company Id due to this i m getting the conversion error. now it has been resolve by changing the fields. Error due to field mismatch. thanks for your help.